# button not rendered correctly in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am trying to add a button per jQuery. It works perfectly in other browsers, IE9 fails.

Code:

```
function AddUnsubscribeButton()
{
    var btn = $('<button/>',
    {
    type: 'button',
    text: 'Unsubscribe',
    id: 'btnUnsubscribe',
    click: function () { AddCurrentUserToSubscriptionList("Unsubscribe");return false; }
    });

    var divBtns = $(".divButtons").parent();
    divBtns.find('#btnSubscribe').remove();
    if(divBtns.first().children().length == 2)
    {   
    divBtns.first().append(btn);
    }
}
```

In IE9 page source it shows this:

```
< button id="btnUnsubscribe" type="button" jQuery17207435150102662105="16" >
```

What am I missing?

Also in the page it doesn't render as a button, it shows only the button text - `Unsubscribe`.
But I need it to show as a button just like it works in other browsers.

It seems IE9 is not rendering the ending tag.

Comment: I just copied your code, it's seems to work in IE9...

Comment: same here dude, just try to re-install your IE9

Comment: Shot in the dark but would changing this: `var btn = $('<button/>',` to this `var btn = $('<button></button>',` make a difference for you?

Comment: It's probably an issue with strict/quirks rendering in IE9. Use a proper HTML5 doctype and UTF8 meta tag as the first child of the head tag and it will work correctly.

Comment: thank you for all your comments. i didnt mention that the page is generated by Sharepoint, perhaps Sharepoint breaks it somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually setting the properties of the element wrong. A button element does'nt have a button type, so you should either use an input element, which has a `type=button` or drop the type.

```
function AddUnsubscribeButton() {
    var btn = $('<button />', {text: 'Unsubscribe', id: 'btnUnsubscribe'});

    btn.on('click', function() {
        AddCurrentUserToSubscriptionList("Unsubscribe");
        return false;
    });

    var divBtns = $(".divButtons").parent();
    divBtns.find('#btnSubscribe').remove();

    if(divBtns.first().children().length == 2) {   
        divBtns.first().append(btn);
    }
}
```

It also seems like adding a click function directly in the properties on the element appends some strangeness in IE, and the proper way to do it would be to use a click event handler, like above.

Comment: thank you for your answer I will try this. However i see in the xhtml reference that button actually does have a type attribute? Am I missing something? http://xhtml.com/en/xhtml/reference/button/

Comment: Depends on the DOCTYPE, but yes, a button element can have a type submit for instance, which would be valid, but setting a button to type `button` does'nt really make much sense in most cases. The click function is probably what messes it up, as adding a click function like that in the properties map is'nt really good practice.

Comment: Your solution works in jsfiddle so I will mark this as the answer. However, in my sharepoint project, for some reason, this doesnt work in IE9 (other browsers work perfectly) - IE9 does not close the button tag no matter what I try. I will post what I found to be working.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from adeneo works in jsFiddle, but did not work for my sharepoint project. For some reason, IE9 refuses to close the button tag, while other browsers work perfectly.

Here is what did work:

```
function AddUnsubscribeButton() {

  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = 'Unsubscribe';
  button.onclick = function(){
    AddCurrentUserToSubscriptionList("Unsubscribe");
    return false;
  };
  var divBtns = $(".divButtons").parent();
  divBtns.find('#btnSubscribe').remove();

  if(divBtns.first().children().length == 2) {   
    divBtns.first().append(button);
  } 
}
```

Hope this will help someone someday.